# Soap web service and android client using ksoap protocal mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I have and android client, that uses ksoap to communicate with a wsdl web service written in c# asp.net. I have a problem with matching the argument types between the web service and the client.
The web server expects to this kind of request (auto generated):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetDetails xmlns="http://host.org/">
      <event_id>int</event_id>
    </GetDetails>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

the client sends requests using ksoap, and they look like this:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <v:Header />
       <v:Body>
           <n0:GetDetails id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org">
              <event_id i:type="d:int">1</event_id>
           </n0:GetDetails>
       </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

For some reason the WS parses the following' client's request as 0 (I guess because of the additional type attributes - i:type="d:int") when the request is assembled manually to look like the first option, it works correctly.
How can i make the web service read the ksoap format correctly or how can i change it's expected format to look like ksoap request. (the web service soap protocol is auto generated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution has 2 parts:
1.  regarding removing the attribute types, I found the answer here:
[using addMapping without the "i:type=" attribute in ksoap2 for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410006/using-addmapping-without-the-itype-attribute-in-ksoap2-for-android)
I neede to set:

```
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
```

2. The name space has to end with a backspace, and i missed it.