# Ksoap for android not able to create the good soapEnvelop

Tags: android, soap, android-ksoap2

The soap that I want is like this:

```
<int:userId>......</int:userId>
```

This is tested in SoapUI and with this I get the proper response back.
What Ksoap makes is this:

```
<userId i:type="n0:undefined" xmlns:n0="http://namespace.com">.....</userId>
```

If I where to paste this code into SoapUI I get an error

```
'<Message>Error in line 5 position 88. Element 'http://namespace.com:
 userId'  
 contains data of the 'http://namespace.com:undefined' data contract.
 The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract. 
 Add the type corresponding to 'undefined' to the list of known types - 
 for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by 
 adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
 </Message>
```

Maybe I am looking in the wrong direction for the solution but I am now asking how can I make ksoap omit the `i:type` part. If anyone can provide a different sollution, you will have my thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KSoap does have a tendancy to insert its own namespaces into each tag, which can give the output you're seeing.

I had a similar such problem, which was easily resolved using the following :

```
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
```

Please also have a look at this [other question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410006/using-addmapping-without-the-itype-attribute-in-ksoap2-for-android).